# SVG Rect positioning inside div is incorrect

Tags: html, css, svg, position

I have put SVG rects inside div:

```
    <div id="box1">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="102px" height="171px">
            <rect width="102px" height="171px" style="fill:#00ACEC; fill-opacity:1;"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="162px" height="14px">
            <rect width="162px" height="14px" style="fill:#BEBEBE; fill-opacity:1;"/>
    </div>
```

The two rects appear properly aligned at bottom.

However if I decrease the height by 2px and update top accordingly, the svg rect appears shifted downwards, whereas it should still be bottom aligned as before.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/mw1skze1/3/

The problem occurs with smaller rects. Am I missing something or this is an issue with svg rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: add css position inherit to the svg.

```
position: inherit
```

The divs are well aligned. You can see the alignment in the Fiddle I have added border to the divs so that you can judge their alignment.

Its the svg and div for the box4 not aligned well.

```
border:1px solid red;
```

have a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/2dc3waqt/

Comment: Can you please tell me why the svg and div for box4 are not aligned, though they align well when I give bigger height and change top accordingly, without adding css position inherit?

Comment: SVG doesnt inherit position from parent.

Comment: I mean how its positioned as expected, when height is large, but its not as expected when height is smaller. Or can you please update my example for larger rects which also have problem?